# Make an Altair map with interactive pan and zoom

Tags: python, maps, geopandas, altair

I am able to generate a world choropleth map with tooltips on mouseover and click selection to grey out unselected countries. I would like to be able to click on a country and have the map pan and zoom in. I have figured out how to use lon/lat centroids for each country and manually change the scale/lon/lat to pan and zoom, but I am struggling how to change lon/lat via the selection method so a user can click on a country to zoom in (also, I would need to be able to zoom back to the default full view somehow). Is it possible somehow to use `transform_calculate` or something to assign values to lon/lat? Thanks.
(map data is from [naturalearthdata](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-admin-0-countries/))

```
import altair as alt
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import numpy as np

world_shp =  gpd.read_file('data_world/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp')[['ADMIN', 'geometry']]
world_shp.rename(columns={'ADMIN': 'Country'}, inplace=True)
world_shp = world_shp.drop(159)  # remove antarctica
world_shp.sort_values(by='Country')

# Add centroids
world_shp['centroid_lon'] = world_shp['geometry'].centroid.x
world_shp['centroid_lat'] = world_shp['geometry'].centroid.y

# Add column to map_df of some dummy data to plot
dummy = np.random.randint(10, 1000, len(world_shp))
world_shp['Cases'] = dummy

# Setup data
world_json = json.loads(world_shp.to_json())
world_data = alt.Data(values=world_json['features'])

# Plotting:
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['properties.Cases'])

color = alt.condition(
    selection,
    alt.Color('properties.Cases', 
              type='quantitative',
              scale=alt.Scale(scheme='bluegreen')),
              alt.value('lightgray')
)

# Add Choropleth Layer
world = alt.Chart(world_data).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color=color,
    tooltip=['properties.Country:O', 'properties.Cases:Q']
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=400
).add_selection(
    selection
)

# Add top layer to mark boundaries
boundaries = alt.Chart(world_data, title='Title Here').mark_geoshape(
    stroke='white',
    strokeWidth=1,
    fill=None
)

world + boundaries
```

And the manual method to pan/zoom:

```
centroid = 'China'

lon = world_shp[world_shp['Country'] == centroid]['centroid_lon'].iloc[0]
lat = world_shp[world_shp['Country'] == centroid]['centroid_lat'].iloc[0]

world.project(
    scale=250, 
    center=[lon, lat]
)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Comment: FYI - It looks like this is the relevant Vega-lite feature necessary in order for this to be possible with Altair: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3306

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is currently not possible in Atair/Vegalite and is being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3306).